# Ordered field of rationals axiomatizable

Tags: model-theory, ordered-fields

Is there a set of sentences in the language of ordered fields whose models are precisely the rationals and any ordered field isomorphic to them?

Comment: No, Upwards Lowenheim-Skolem says that if you have an infinite model, then you have models are arbitrarily large cardinality.  If $\mathbb{Q}$ is a model, then you'll have uncountable ones.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer is no. For by the) [Lowenheim-Skolem theorem,](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%C3%B6wenheim%E2%80%93Skolem_theorem) if the set $T$ of statements has an infinite model, then $T$ has models of arbitrarily high cardinality.

Answer (score 6):

No, for obvious reasons.

There is exactly one field isomorphic to the rational numbers. The rational numbers. Even if you mean order isomorphic, and not ordered-field isomorphic, these are all countable fields.

And of course there is no set of axioms which have an infinite model only of one cardinality in first-order logic. So this is impossible.

But even if you limit yourself to countable fields this is not possible. Take any uncountable model of this set of axioms, then it has at least one number which is irrational and not algebraic; call it $t$. Now look at the least elementary submodel containing $t$, this is a countable field which has an irrational number. So it's not isomorphic to $\Bbb Q$.

Comment: Your last-described object is a countable field that contains an irrational, but is it a countable structure that contains an irrational and satisfies all of the first-order formulas satisfied by $\mathbb Q$? ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: Michael, sure. If you start with $T=\rm Th(\Bbb Q,0,1,+,\cdot)$, and take $t$ to be an irrational number in an uncountable model of $T$, you get exactly that. If $t$ was a real number, you get some $\Bbb Q(t)$ for some transcendental $t$; otherwise you are probably going to get a non-Archimedean extension.

Comment: @AsafKaragila, strictly speaking that isn't enough to conclude that there is a field $\mathbb{Q}\subset F\subset\mathbb{R}$ which is elementarily equivalent to $\mathbb{Q}$. And this isn't trivially fixed: if we adjoin, say, a constant symbol $c$ and look at the theory of $\mathbb{Q}$ with $c=\pi$, there's no a priori reason that the resulting field is isomorphic to a subfield of $\mathbb{R}$. For example, we could have an element in the same Dedekind cut as $\sqrt{2}$ which does not square to 2. (cont'd)

Comment: As far as I can tell, the fastest way to show that such an $F$ exists is to show - via Ehrenfeucht-Fraisse games - that $\mathbb{Q}[r]$ is elementarily equivalent to $\mathbb{Q}$ precisely when $r$ is transcendental. Of course we don't need such a field to answer the OP, but the existence of such a field is nice. And this is a nice application of EF-games.

Comment: @user28111: I see what you mean. Thanks.

Comment: @user28111: Do note,  by the way, that I only said that *if* $t$ happened to be a real number, then $\Bbb Q(t)$ is a transcendental extension. Because this is a submodel of $\Bbb R$ (not elementary, of course).

Answer (score 2):

The existence of such a set of sentences is precluded by the compactness theorem of first-order logic.  Consider the sentences
\begin{align}
a & > 1 \\
a+a & > 1 \\
a+a+a & > 1 \\
a+a+a+a & > 1 \\
& \,\,\, \vdots
\end{align}
Every finite subset of this set is satisfiable within the rationals.  Therefore by the compactness theorem, all of them are simultaneously satisfiable in a structure satisfying all first-order sentences true in $\mathbb Q$.  But such a structure clearly cannot be isomorphic to $\mathbb Q$.